# HTML Canvas, with React hooks and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas, react-hooks, use-effect

I was trying to create a canvas element with some basic shapes, using React hooks and Typescript, but I'm running into an error where the context in useEffect() could be null (ts2531).

I'm assuming this is because my canvasRef is null by default, but I'm a bit unsure what else I can set it to, or if there is a better way to go about this?

Here is my code so far (edit, solution below):

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

interface CanvasProps {
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

const Canvas = ({ width, height }: CanvasProps) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (canvasRef.current) {
            const canvas = canvasRef.current;
            const context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
            context.beginPath();
+           context.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
+           context.fill(); 
        }       
    },[]);

    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} height={height} width={width} />;
};

Canvas.defaultProps = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
};

export default Canvas;
```

Following Alex Wayne's speedy answer, here is my updated useEffect(), which works.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
        if (context) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.fill(); 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Typescript is just saying you need to check that canvas isn't null before working with it. You can also search for the typescript error/warning number to get more info. @aamirl ...what?

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply's everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) `getContext('2d')` can return `null`.

> If the contextType doesn't match a possible drawing context, null is returned.

So `const context` has a type that might be null. You can be pretty sure it's not but you just have to check it.

```
if (canvasRef.current) {
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (context) {
    // use context here.
  }
}
```

With optional chaining you can avoid nesting if's here with something like:

```
const context = canvasRef.current?.getContext('2d')
if (context) {
  // use context here.
}
```

Comment: This 'canvasRef.current?.getContext('2d')' worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `getContext` can return `null`. Docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext

> If the contextType doesn't match a possible drawing context, null is returned.

## Fix

Ensure it's not `null` e.g.

```
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
        if (context == null) throw new Error('Could not get context');
        // now safe
```